# Cascade.ALL, but just clearing reference on delete?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, cascade

I have a @ManyToOne entry within one of my entities. If I delete the surrounding entity, I'm getting a `deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)`

But I need the cascade option there, so: how can I cascade anywhing *beside* delete, respectively just *clear* the reference instead of cascading the deletion?

Comment: What do you call the surrounding entity? Could you provide your code the entities, their mapping, and the code triggering the exception)?

Comment: The obvious answer would be too simply manually specify the cascade options for the association, and exclude 'REMOVE'. But if you are getting that error message something is probably wrong with the structure of your code. As @JBNizet commented, we need to see your code setup. Include the relevant portions of both the 'parent' and child entity, showing all annotations you are currently defining.